# Modifying cells in SQL Server Management Studio 2005 without a mouse

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssms

I'm always making manual changes to a lot of data as part of my job. One thing I've noticed is that I can use the arrow keys to browse around to different cells when viewing the data. But when I go to a new cell, the entire text in it is highlighted. How can I use my keyboard to say I want a cursor so I can modify the text without clicking in it using my mouse?

Comment: +1 for asking, this was annoying the heck out of me.  I was about to ask "Edit Column Names and Data in MS SQL Server EM or SSMS without Using the Mouse" but SO found this related question for me.  It's a waste of time to reach all the way over there for the mouse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click F2 to start modifying.

Comment: Perfectooo! (This 10 character business is annoying me)

Comment: +1 Just tested in 2008 and it works here too.  I also use the arrows and was trying other keys like Home and End to edit, but none worked.  Thanks for F2.